# Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, import, dataflow

During article import of a custom import profile (Dataflow - Profiles) I get this error for all rows:

```
Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined.
```

I have mapped "sku" => "artnr" (Field Mapping) but it looks like he does not use this, even I have `Original Magento attribute names in first row` set to `No`.

If I rename the column in my csv file and set `Original Magento attribute ...` to `Yes` it works. (He complains about empty type instead)

Same problem with normal Import: `"Can not find required columns: sku"`. I changed column name from artnr to sku and stored the file as utf8.

Columns look like this at the moment:

```
store;websites;attribute_set;type;category_ids;sku_wrong;has_options;name;weight;image;small_image;thumbnail;url_key;url_path;package_content;unit;sku;price;manufacturer;status;tax_class_id;visibility;gesamtrabatt;description;short_description;gift_message_available;qty;min_qty;use_config_min_qty;is_qty_decimal;backorders;use_config_backorders;min_sale_qty;use_config_min_sale_qty;max_sale_qty;use_config_max_sale_qty;is_in_stock;low_stock_date;notify_stock_qty;use_config_notify_stock_qty;manage_stock;use_config_manage_stock;stock_status_changed_automatically;use_config_qty_increments;qty_increments;use_config_enable_qty_increments;enable_qty_increments;product_name;store_id;product_type_id;product_status_changed;product_changed_websites
"";"";"Default";"";"";"";"0";"Br&ouml;tchen";"";"?";"?";"";"";"";"";"St&uuml;ck";"10412";".24";"";"";"";"";"0";"Artikel f&uuml;r die Demonstration von Folgeartikel.";"";"";"";"";"";"";"0";"";"1";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"0";"Br&ouml;tchen";"";"";"";""
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use the Dataflow import. It is a quite old module and has some disadvantages, i.e. speed. I would not suggest to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the following steps:

- convert to utf8
- remove empty "sku" column
- rename "artnr" to "sku"
- set column "type" to "simple" for all rows
- clear column "image" and "small_image": "?" => ""

And now the import tells me "Processed 100% 11/11 records", "Imported 11 records". All green, all good but the new products are not listed in the catalog.

I guess I am still [missing some columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12440138/956397). If that does not help it would be worth a new question.

Comment: "Processed 100% 11/11 records" would sugest they should now appear in the admin section. Check that first.

In your Columns i notice you dont have information filled in for 'store' , this means your products have imported but are not yet assigned to any particular store.

Also;
After importing products always re-index all your indexes (even if the admin screen suggests they don't need it, do it again anyway., and wait for them to completely finish...

Comment: On top of converting to UTF-8... I recommend opening the file in Notepad++ to see if there are any characters that are not standard.

Answer (score 2):

At least for the standard import, the column separator is comma: `,` - not semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

PI, there is an attribute for products that make the product visible. I do not see it in your mapping, include it and you should be ok

Comment: I did have `visibility` but other fields were missing, see [my solution](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3983/137). But thanks for your effort!