# Magento Import Problem For same csv

Tags: magento-1.7, product, import, csv

Hello I am trying to upload product attribute value for french store. but some of csv row not able to execute and giving Error "Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined.".

For getting solution of this problem i export particular one product and just change data below header row.

Even if they are giving me same error and any body have any idea ? i am using open office.

both csv placed here origanal [csv](http://dev.starcufflinks.co.uk/export_product_org.csv) and

[modified csv](http://dev.starcufflinks.co.uk/export_product_modified.csv)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

- convert to utf8
- remove empty "sku" column
- rename "artnr" to "sku"
- set column "type" to "simple" for all rows
- clear column "image" and "small_image": "?" => ""

This [LINK](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3973/skipping-import-row-required-field-sku-is-not-defined) can be a help.

Comment: Thanks For Reply...@TBI infotech you should look at both csv what i am trying to say.

Comment: I see there are special characters in your file. Open file in editor may be notepad ++, then from encoding first select "Convert to UTF-8 without BOM", and then select "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM". Then save file and without opening it open import it and check.

Comment: @TBIInfotech , I could not find out these coloumns. Thanks.